# How can I add gift option in Magento 1.9?

Tags: php, magento

I am using `magento 1.9.1.`

How can I add gift option for product?

What I did is I add a product,  `Catalog->Manage Product->Add product.`

Put `Attribute Set` as `Default` and `Product Type` as `Simple Product`.
And I put `general, prices, images` etc informations for the product. Now I want to add **Gift Options**.

When I click `Gift Options` link a page is displayed. Please refer the image given below.
[image]

But I don't know how to add `Gift Options` here?

Please help me...Any help is really appreciable..

Thank you..

Comment: have enable the gift option in `system > configuration > sales > gift option` for item level gift option ?

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR, I enabled..But still i don't know how to add Gift Option?

Answer (score 0):

Magento community edition doesn't provide the facility of gift options and gift cards. You have to customize what you want to achieve.